# Get a Combined Result in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 5 tables in Mysql and i need a combined result from all the tables
The tables are as follows

***1)library_book_relation***

```
CREATE TABLE db.library_book_relation ( 
    id                   int  NOT NULL  AUTO_INCREMENT  PRIMARY KEY,
    library_id             int      ,
    book_item_id      int      ,
    seller_price         decimal(10,2)      ,
    pack_quantity        decimal(10,2)      ,
    is_discontinue       tinyint      ,
    total_quantity       decimal(10,2)      ,     
 ) ;
```

***2)book_item***

```
CREATE TABLE db.`book_item` ( 
    id                   int  NOT NULL  AUTO_INCREMENT  PRIMARY KEY,
    book_id           int      ,
    size_unit_id         tinyint      ,
    size                 decimal(10,2)      ,
    is_active            boolean      ,
    is_deleted           boolean      ,   
 )  ;
```

***3) book***

```
CREATE TABLE db.book( 
    id                   int  NOT NULL  AUTO_INCREMENT  PRIMARY KEY,
    name                 varchar(100)      ,
    author_id             int      ,
    description          varchar(256)      ,
    is_active            boolean      ,
    is_deleted           boolean      ,

 ) ;
```

***4) author***

```
CREATE TABLE db.author( 
    id                   int  NOT NULL  AUTO_INCREMENT  PRIMARY KEY,
    name                 varchar(100)      ,
    image                varchar(256)      ,
    description          varchar(256)      ,
    is_active            tinyint      ,
    is_deleted           tinyint      ,
 ) ;
```

***5)size_unit***

```
CREATE TABLE db.size_unit ( 
    id                   tinyint  NOT NULL    PRIMARY KEY,
    name                 varchar(100)      ,
    is_active            tinyint      ,
 ) ;
```

***i want a combined result where i get***

```
author id
author name 
count of books for the author in library
```

***i got all 3 in different queries but dont know how to combine the result***

***to get author id and name***

```
select id,name FROM author where id IN( select e.id from author e inner join book r on e.id = r.author_id where r.id IN( select q.id from book q inner join book_item w on q.id = w.book_id where w.id IN( Select s.id from book_item s inner join library_book_relation d on s.id=d.book_item_id where d.library_id = 1 )))
```

***to get count of books for author in library***

```
(Select COUNT(*) FROM book where author_id IN ( select e.id from author e inner join book r on e.id = r.author_id where r.id IN( select q.id from book q inner join book_item w on q.id = w.book_id where w.id IN( Select s.id from book_item s inner join library_book_relation d on s.id=d.book_item_id where d.library_id = 1 ))) GROUP BY author_id)
```

Comment: how you can tell that particular `author_id` is discontinued?

Comment: dont need that anymore just the other 2 @zealous

Comment: As to your queries: I prefer `IN` and `EXISTS` over joins where we have the choice, but here we haven't, because you don't merely want to know *whether* a an author is prresent in a library, but *how often*. You need joins for this. (Or a subquery in the select clause as an alternative.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to join all tables, group by author and library and count:

```
select b.author_id, a.name, lbr.library_id, count(*)
from book b
join book_item bi on bi.book_id = b.id
join library_book_relation lbr on lbr.book_item_id = bi.id
join author a on a.id = b.author_id
group by b.author_id, a.name, lbr.library_id
order by b.author_id, a.name, lbr.library_id;
```

Per SQL standard you only need to `group by b.author_id, lbr.library_id`, because you want one result row per author and library. MySQL should be able to do this, so you can remove `a.name` from the group by clause. (There is only one name per author ID.)

You can also count before joining with the authors table. It is considered good style to aggregate before joining and can help a lot (or be even necessary) in more complicated queries.

```
select c.author_id, a.name, c.library_id, c.books
from
(
  select b.author_id, lbr.library_id, count(*) as books
  from book b
  join book_item bi on bi.book_id = b.id
  join library_book_relation lbr on lbr.book_item_id = bi.id
  group by b.author_id, lbr.library_id
) c
join author a on a.id = c.author_id
order by c.author_id, a.name, c.library_id;
```

Above queries do not count zeros, though. They just show how often to find authors in the libraries. Here is how to count how many books author #1 has in library #123:

```
select a.id, a.name, coalesce(b.books, 0)
from author a
left join
(
  select b.author_id, count(*) as books
  from book b
  join book_item bi on bi.book_id = b.id
  join library_book_relation lbr on lbr.book_item_id = bi.id
  where lbr.library_id = 123
  group by b.author_id
) c on c.author_id = a.id
where a.id = 1;
```

Or with the subquery in the select clause:

```
select
  a.id,
  a.name, 
  (
    select count(*)
    from book b
    join book_item bi on bi.book_id = b.id
    join library_book_relation lbr on lbr.book_item_id = bi.id
    where lbr.library_id = 123
    and b.author_id = a.id
  ) as books
from author a
where a.id = 1;
```

At last a query to get all authors and all libraries including zeros:

```
select a.id as author_id, a.name, l.id as library_id, coalesce(c.books, 0)
from author a
cross join library l
left join
(
  select b.author_id, lbr.library_id, count(*) as books
  from book b
  join book_item bi on bi.book_id = b.id
  join library_book_relation lbr on lbr.book_item_id = bi.id
  group by b.author_id, lbr.library_id
) c on c.author_id = a.id and c.library_id = l.id
order by a.id, l.id;
```